# determine when an R base function was added

Tags: r

Is there a way to determine rather easily when an R function was added (what version number).  Take for instance when were:

`paste0` and `browseVignettes` added?

I'm not really looking for when these were added but a way to see when they were added.

Comment: just do the google search here - https://svn.r-project.org/R-dev-web/trunk/index.html

Comment: @eddi very reasonable approach +1 (I like GSee's programmatic approach a little better (may wrap it up as a function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer as requested:

You can use the `news()` function

```
news(grepl("paste0", Text))
```

Comment: Although that news database only goes back to R 2.10.0. The R sources include text files `ONEWS` and `OONEWS` that together go back to R-0.50, but I can't immediately find how to get them loaded into the database accessed by `news()`.  I suppose one could paste them together into `NEWS` and then recompile R, but that seems like a heavy handed solution. Anyone know another way?

Answer (score 1):

Go here: http://cran.r-project.org/src/base/NEWS.html

`paste0` was in 2.15.0 <strike>and `browseVignettes` was 2.13.0</strike> but it doesn't seem to mention `browseVignettes`.

Comment: or, from R, `db <- news();db[grepl("paste0", db$Text), ]`

Comment: @GSee this was the kind of answer I was looking for.  Can you post it as an answer?